# Pull email-to-case configuration from scratch org and deploy it through unlocked package along with recordTypes

Tags: email2case

I would like to pull the email-to-case (E2C) metadata from scratch with **Case Record Type**, save them in our Version Control System and deploy it through unlocked package (changing/removing EmailServicesAddress attribute in our CI pipelines). How can we retrieve the E2C metadata with **Case Record Type** from scratch?

With below package.xml format, I get all details of E2C, but without **Case Record Type** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>Case</members>
    <name>Settings</name>
  </types>
<version>50.0</version>
</Package>
```

Basically, I am looking to retrieve below highlighted field data while retrieving E2C data from Scratch org :

[image]